# Is it worth caching simple MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql, caching, apc

I have a PHP script that runs very simple queries on a MySQL database (up to a maximum of 25 times per page). Is it going to be worth caching the results (e.g. using APC), or is the performance difference likely to be negligible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caching is just about always worth it.  Pulling it from APC's in memory user cache vs. establishing a db connection and running queries is a massive difference--especially if you're doing 25 queries on a page!

The benefits will compound:

1. Pulling from memory you'll serve up requests faster by requiring less overhead
2. You'll free up db connections
3. You'll free up apache processes faster
4. All of which will help server up request faster...

Comment: Even though I tend to agree I am not completely convinced... Consider having properly configured a connection pool we do not need the time to establish a connection. Then if the query is executed regularly it is most likely in the database memory, so it would not be slower than the cache, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Tim Reaching into local memory vs. sending a query  and having mysql evaluate whether it's in memory or not, if not parse the query, plan, then execute is  going to be faster.  Plus you're stacking a lot of if's to try and get an opposite answer.   Why not loop through 10,000 query requests each way and see for yourself the results.

Comment: You are right, especially the query planning slipped my mind, thank you for the explanation!